# smart way to delete unused images in containerd except a few in aws eks 1.24

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, containerd

I have a bunch of unused images. The following will output all images (some of them are used by currently running containers

```bash
ctr -n k8s.io i ls | grep "dev-" | wc -l
139
```

Is there a proper way to prune just specific **unused** images from

- a specific registry(ies)
- or by having a specific prefix of the tag, i.e. `dev-`

I was doing this in docker and it was working

```
docker ps --filter "status=exited" -q | xargs -r docker rm && docker image prune --all
```

I tried similar with

```
crictl rmi --prune
```

and it crashed my aws eks node, because apparently - that also deletes paused containers for which images are required to be on the node.

Comment: My experience with EKS has been that you can't log into the nodes directly, so you can't run any of the commands you show here.  The cluster already knows how to delete unused images from nodes so this shouldn't be a task you need to do manually in any case.  This is much more of a system-administration question than a programming question, though, and another site like [devops.se] or [sf] might be a more appropriate place to ask.

Comment: you can start a privileged container and get inside any node to run any tasks that require root level ops or use `aws ssm` to get inside any node if you have ssm agent enabled. See this: https://gist.github.com/dmitry-mightydevops/8478f7d03bdc10b934c19cb005421111
@DavidMaze

Comment: Maybe this automated way is interesting https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/eks-worker-nodes-image-cache